# How can I rename my email account's default "Sent" folder label in Outlook 2013 (via Exchange server)?

Tags: email, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013, rename, sent-items

**Q. How can I *rename* my email account's default "Sent" folder...**

My "Sent" folder in Outlook 2013 email account (via Exchange server) is incorrectly labelled as "Payslip 1.jpg" (with Windows 7 Pro 64Bit PC). Yeah, I know... I'm not joking! :-(

[image]

I had a PC malfunction (crash or something??, as I can't quite recall how it all happened) whilst saving an image in Photoshop (I think). Upon restarting and returning to Outlook, my Sent folder had been renamed (to the filename I was working on... yes, in a completely different application). I don't know how this all transpired, but I can't seem to adjust the folder name now.

It shows up on any other instance of my mail-box on another PC with Outlook, and also on the Outlook web client. The only place it seems okay is on my iPhone when connected to my exchange account, where it is shown as "Sent".

[image]

The functionality of this folder is still treated as the "Sent" folder, so that new messages are saved automatically in this folder, and are referenced to this folder (on searches).

*PS : No comments needed on number of items in my Inbox, unless it relates  **;-p***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the free tools available to fix the name:

1. [MFCMAPI](https://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/): Session -> Logon, open required store, Open Root -> IPM_SUBTREE, click on the "Payslip 1.jpg" folder and edit PR_DISPLAY_NAME property as needed.
2. [Set Outlook Folder Property](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookFolderPropertiesSet) utility: select the "Payslip 1.jpg" folder **only** (without subfolders), type "DisplayName" as a property name, "Sent Items" as a Value to set (all without quotes) and click Run.

Comment: Are these running directly on exchange server?  I only have client access on a shared hosted service?

Comment: No need to run it on Exchange. Outlook is required only.